# Artist info missing from Facebook Graph API /music.listens endpoint

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm playing around w/ the /me/music.listens endpoint of Graph API and I have it working just fine. Except I can't seem to figure out how to get actual artist info to come back. I see the song and even the album (though that seems a little inconsistent too). But never any artist info.

Check the developer explorer here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fmusic.listens

No artist info. Is this just not returned? I can't see how to specify this in a fields param list. FB's documentation of the actions is spotty at best so I figured I'd try here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a work around. It doesn't look like Facebook actually returns artist info. So you have to use the Spotify Lookup Service (http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/lookup/).

To break it down a little further, you start by pulling the music.listens feed from FB and you'll get info that looks like:

```
                 (
                   [song] => Array
                        (
                         [id] => 381659191902248
                         [url] => http://open.spotify.com/track/**2Vv27Gc5k5GgGW9jgtj1CS**
                         [type] => music.song
                         [title] => Follow Through
                        )
                    )
```

From there, you need to grab the bolded track ID.

Lastly, fetch the song metadata with this call to Spotify: http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/.json?uri=spotify:track:2Vv27Gc5k5GgGW9jgtj1CS

You'll be returned the album name, artist info, etc.

If someone knows a better way, lemme know!

Comment: Ever figure out a better solution?  It looks like Facebook has potential to return "musicians" but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve artists informations on graph API with the song id :

https://graph.facebook.com/song_id?fields=data{musician}

ex : https://graph.facebook.com/697975930266172?fields=data{musician}

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know, but you can retrieve related information such as both the song title and artist title in the same request using Graph API's 'field expansion'.

For example - Last 10 songs

`me?fields=music.listens.limit(10){data{song{title,id},musician{id,title}}}`

To retrieve more information from either the song or musician entities just tweak the fields requested.

Note, this requires `user_actions.music` permission